# how to play one of animation from animations

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

i am making a 2D game, and i have a problem. My main character in this game is a farmer, he can hoe, watering plant, and mowing plant.
When my main character is in idle position, and he ask to hoe the land, i have to play "princeForkBronzeFront" animation. But i don't know how to make it work. does anyone know how to play animation from Animations? Thank you.

I tried this code too, but it didn't work.

```
animations.Play("princeForkBronzeFront");
StartCoroutine(WaitAnimation(animations));
```

and wait animation function is

```
private IEnumerator WaitAnimation(Animation anim)
{
    do{
        yield return null;
    }while(anim.isPlaying);
}
```

[image: animations in animation]

Comment: are your animations sprite sheet? you can just have your animations in diffrent sprite sheets and for every event or situation just play one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an [animator](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Animator.html).
It can perform all the actions you need.
It can manage when to play certain animations, what to do after this animation has finished playing, blend multiple animations together...
For youtube tutorials, click [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeZkctmoBPw).

Comment: Well, thank you for your help. I know how to use animator. But my problem is, when my main character in idle position, and he ask to hoe, i want to play that "princeForkBronzeFront" animation. And when "princeForkBronzeFront" finish, i want to play "idle" animation again. I am really confused to make it. Can you help me? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use State Machine with Animator. [Here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StateMachineBasics.html) it is well explained. State Machine is the best method while working with animations.